# PostgreSQL. Работа с JSON

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Есть таблица mytable:

```
CREATE TABLE public.newtable (
    id int4 NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    fquestions jsonb NULL   
);
INSERT
    INTO
    public.newtable(fquestions)
VALUES ('{"mid":"1ed506a3-7eb8-66a2-9dcb-efg16dd2ed59c9","mname":"Т№1","questionSections":[{"qsid":"1ed506a6-81d8-6d48-8b5c-d111c6b99f2b","qsname":"Рожэлэ","questions":[{"qid":"1ed506c6-703e-6f2c-aa44-6dzc1zc7a3501","qname":"лььрпд?","optionSections":[{"osid":"1ed506c9-8ad6-688c-94bf-c5616czx6cz49ce8d","osname":"ЛЬЖОТжи","questionOptions":[{"qoid":"1ed506cb-e830-61b6-b290-f718c1xz6c1z6b5e","value":"тщтщжгртб"},{"qoid":"1ed506cc-b73f-69ca-867a-df77xz6c16za3397","value":"тщтщхощэсасе"},{"qoid":"1ed506cd-7b97-6408-a3ad-cd204c1z61ze4cc","value":"лишижимсасп"}]}]},{"qid":"1ed506d0-6746-6de8-8358-15ag6fh4f6g1bb0","qname":" ил илиижиримо","optionSections":[{"osid":"1ed506d2-ed16-6c5a-b945-63fgf6h16f1792","osname":"лоилилилиири","questionOptions":[{"qoid":"1ed506d6-d820-6072-bddd-6f80g1gf4gfe88","value":"646132"},{"qoid":"1ed506d7-7586-6366-a9ee-db14fdgfd69f01","value":"ьдтотои"},{"qoid":"1e1df1g6d8-6288-64c0-a985-5ba1fd1g6753a","value":"аспааппо"}]}]}]}]}');
```

JSON:

```
{
  "mid": "1ed506a3-7eb8-66a2-9dcb-efg16dd2ed59c9",
  "mname": "Т№1",
  "questionSections": [
    {
      "qsid": "1ed506a6-81d8-6d48-8b5c-d111c6b99f2b",
      "qsname": "Рожэлэ",
      "questions": [
        {
          "qid": "1ed506c6-703e-6f2c-aa44-6dzc1zc7a3501",
          "qname": "лььрпд?",
          "optionSections": [
            {
              "osid": "1ed506c9-8ad6-688c-94bf-c5616czx6cz49ce8d",
              "osname": "ЛЬЖОТжи",
              "questionOptions": [
                {
                  "qoid": "1ed506cb-e830-61b6-b290-f718c1xz6c1z6b5e",
                  "value": "тщтщжгртб"
                },
                {
                  "qoid": "1ed506cc-b73f-69ca-867a-df77xz6c16za3397",
                  "value": "тщтщхощэсасе"
                },
                {
                  "qoid": "1ed506cd-7b97-6408-a3ad-cd204c1z61ze4cc",
                  "value": "лишижимсасп"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "qid": "1ed506d0-6746-6de8-8358-15ag6fh4f6g1bb0",
          "qname": " ил илиижиримо",
          "optionSections": [
            {
              "osid": "1ed506d2-ed16-6c5a-b945-63fgf6h16f1792",
              "osname": "лоилилилиири",
              "questionOptions": [
                {
                  "qoid": "1ed506d6-d820-6072-bddd-6f80g1gf4gfe88",
                  "value": "646132"
                },
                {
                  "qoid": "1ed506d7-7586-6366-a9ee-db14fdgfd69f01",
                  "value": "ьдтотои"
                },
                {
                  "qoid": "1e1df1g6d8-6288-64c0-a985-5ba1fd1g6753a",
                  "value": "аспааппо"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Нужен такой результат:

| id | qname | osname | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | лььрпд? | ЛЬЖОТжи | тщтщжгртб |
| 1 | лььрпд? | ЛЬЖОТжи | тщтщхощэсасе |
| 1 | лььрпд? | ЛЬЖОТжи | лишижимсасп |
| 1 | ил илиижиримо | лоилилилиири | 646132 |
| 1 | ил илиижиримо | лоилилилиири | ьдтотои |
| 1 | ил илиижиримо | лоилилилиири | аспааппо |

Как лучше реализовать запрос?

Comment: Ну начать с того, что questionSections в значении как-то не наблюдается...

Comment: Извиняюсь неполный JSON приложил. Добавил в тексте.

Comment: Ну а где требуемый результат для этого JSON? Хотя правильнее было бы выложить не одно значение, а скрипты CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO с таблицей и этим значением.

Comment: Добавил. Сегодня новые вводные получил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как вывести для каждого id все значения name?

```
SELECT 
  test.id,
  question.body->'name' question_name
FROM test
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(test.fquestions) AS question(body);
```

| id | question_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "Вопрос 1? " |
| 1 | "Вопрос 2" |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/upvX_PrP)

---

> Добавил. Сегодня новые вводные получил. – Twanger

```
SELECT 
  test.id,
  q.body->>'qname' qname,
  os.body->>'osname' osname,
  qo.body->>'value' value
FROM test
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(test.fquestions->'questionSections') AS qs(body)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(qs.body->'questions') AS q(body)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(q.body->'optionSections') AS os(body)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(os.body->'questionOptions') AS qo(body)
```

| id | qname | osname | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | лььрпд? | ЛЬЖОТжи | тщтщжгртб |
| 1 | лььрпд? | ЛЬЖОТжи | тщтщхощэсасе |
| 1 | лььрпд? | ЛЬЖОТжи | лишижимсасп |
| 1 | ил илиижиримо | лоилилилиири | 646132 |
| 1 | ил илиижиримо | лоилилилиири | ьдтотои |
| 1 | ил илиижиримо | лоилилилиири | аспааппо |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VILSrKFL)

Comment: Обидно, что сам до этого не дошел. Но теперь буду знать)
Спасибо большое